# botao para acrescentar um minuto

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ola 
eu tenho este código e gostaria de fazer um botao para acrescentar um minuto ao tempo que esta a decorrer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int quick = 1800;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1800;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;


        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            quick--;
            label1.Text = quick / 60 + " : " + ((quick % 60) >= 10 ? (quick % 60).ToString() : "0" + (quick % 60));
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Tente ser mais direto na sua dúvida, fica difícil de saber como ajudar com perguntas muito amplas. Se você já tentou fazer e não obteve sucesso deve haver alguma dúvida mais específica ou um erro que tu não sabes como resolver.

Comment: @CesarGoulart conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: eu queria por um botao para acrescentar um minuto ao tempo, que codigo coloco no botao para funcionar? obg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O interval do seu timer está errado, se você quer uma sincronia com segundos, deve parear com esse intervalo, como ele é atribuído em milisegundos e para que o seu evento `Tick` seja disparado a cada 1s (fazendo o decremento do tempo restante), você deve declarar seu valor como 1000 (1000ms = 1s).Já a parte de exibição, está um pouco confusa e com operações desnecessárias.

Para aumentar o tempo restante, bastava você incrementar o valor no click do botão, no caso, eu adicionei o `button3` para adicionar 60 segundos.

E por fim, você está esquecendo de parar o seu timer após o final do intervalo desejado.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int tempoRestante = 1800;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);            
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tempoRestante <= 0)
            timer1.Stop();
        else
            tempoRestante--;

        int minutos = tempoRestante / 60;
        int segundos = tempoRestante % 60;

        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutos.ToString("#,00"), segundos.ToString("#,00"));

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tempoRestante += 60;

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado esta resolvido. Muito Obrigado Leandro Angelo

Comment: @CesarGoulart Era esse mesmo o problema? Se a proposta é a resposta para a sua pergunta, é importante votar como útil e aceitar como resposta, assim a sua pergunta e a solução podem ser úteis para outros usuários que venham a enfrentar o mesmo problema